# How to use BasicHttpBinding without using sessions in WCF? Getting error about session support

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010

I have a WinForm app which uses WCF to call a WCF service. I am trying to troubleshoot an issue and need to look at the wcf trace file without any encryption. So I  have WCF endpoint set to use BasicHttpBinding and my service contract is set for SessionMode = SessionMode.NotAllowed.

However I keep getting an error "Contract requires Session, but Binding 'BasicHttpBinding' doesn't support it or isn't configured properly to support it".

I don't want to use sessions. Why does it think I want to use sessions?

**OR** how do I get the messages to go on the wire where I can see objects and their properties in clear text in the trace file?

Answer (score 1):

BasicHttpBinding never uses session. There is something incorrectly configured in your code (or you didn't correctly update service reference). To see messages even if security is enabled use [Message logging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064.aspx).